# Text alignment using PARA element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am unable to find out as to why the alignment of `PARA` element is incorrect when I publish the XML to PDF at certain positions.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<PARA0>
<SUBPARA1>
<SUBPARA2>
<TITLE>Title</TITLE>
<PARA>ABCD</PARA>
<RANDLIST PREFIX="SIMPLE">
<ITEM><PARA><EMPHASIS EMPH="BOLD">A1234</EMPHASIS></PARA><PARA
>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</PARA>
</ITEM>
<ITEM><PARA><EMPHASIS EMPH="BOLD">B1234</EMPHASIS></PARA><PARA>
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</PARA>
</ITEM>

</RANDLIST>
</SUBPARA2>
</SUBPARA1>
</PARA0>
```

The XSLT is quite huge , so I am not able to identify the area which needs to be  checked.
I am getting a output like described in this figure below:

[image: figure]

The desired output is like this figure below:

[image]

Could you please help me to form the XSLT to get the correct alignment?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the project and given todo? I doubt, fixing a xslt - we dont see - and rendered by xml element mappings - we dont see - will result in an (good) answer. may you search for "hanging indent framemaker". *A negative first-line indent and a positive rest-of-lines indent is the standard way to do this in all applications that can set mappings*

Comment: @uL1 Thanks. But how do I apply this as a common config for all XMLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the `PARA` alignment right.

We have to mention the alignment and indent settings in the **Paragraph Designer** in Framemaker. It depends on how the `PARA` hierarchy is continued in the document and if it is defined in Framemaker for that particular part of the text. For my case the tag responsible for the document was `'item2suite'`.

So I set the indent and alignment specific to that tag in Framemaker.